# How to handle error in mongoose in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm developing a node.js app with express and mongoDb and mongoose. The app saves the user in the code below with no problem, but in this code it always console error even if the process is success, and the user is saved.

I'm trying to make flash messages and validation but I can't go ahead with this problem.

Also, I'm not sure if I'm using the right post method or not(should I use   res.status(500).send('error')) inside the post?

```
 newUser.save().then(function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error') // always prints this 
  } else {
    console.log('success')
  }
})
```

the full code

```
var User = require('../models/User')
var router = require('express').Router()

 router.route('/user/signup')
.get(function (request, response) {
  // render the form
  response.render('user/signup')
 })
 .post(function (request, response) {
  var username = request.body.name
  var password = request.body.password
  var newUser = new User({
  name: username,
  password: password
  })
  newUser.save().then(function (error) {
    if (error) {
    console.log('error')
  } else {
    console.log('success')
  }
 })
 response.redirect('/')
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to pass the function directly to save() as the callback

```
newUser.save(function (err, user) {
      if (err) ..
    })
```

With the approach you're currently taking, I think you'll want to use `catch`

```
newUser.save().then(function (user) }})
   .catch((err) => ...);
```

[Source: mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_function%20Object()%20%7B%20%5Bnative%20code%5D%20%7D-save)

Comment: True. Is there a better approach without using catch? Because I want to use express validation with flash messages.

Comment: Personally I prefer using async/await:

await newUser.save() but I'm unsure if there's a better way atm